# Decent Clickpass alternative?

Tags: openid, openid-provider, openid-selector

I wanted to use Clickpass in an webapp that I've been developing, as I like the idea of a simpler way of handling OpenID.  However, when I peeked at the developer documentation, I got this:

> "Clickpass is being reworked. Please, don't develop against the current Clickpass implementation."

Are there any decent alternatives to Clickpass, or should I just work a plain-old OpenID library into my site instead?

Comment: is clickpass dead? same message after 2 years!

Comment: I'm one of the founders of Clickpass. We sold the company to Yola.com in 2008 and apart from a few pieces of basic maintenance there hasn't been any major development since then. I have heard some rumblings of the service being resold again but as far as I know it's still in stasis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make that decision based on what libraries exist for your web framework, and just how customizable you need your SSO solution.

If you need something simple up and running as quickly as possible, use one of the existing providers - a common choice is [Janrain Engage (previously RPXNow)](http://www.janrain.com/products/engage).

On the other hand, if you need to customize your login behavior and use advanced features, just roll your own using any existing OpenID lib.

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion of Janrain led me to enough keywords to be able to find alternatives.  As it turns out, the three major players in this area seem to be Janrain, Clickpass and Gigya.  I'll investigate both Janrain and Gigya unless Clickpass releases its new API sometime soon.  Thanks.